# Adsense API data in local timezone

Tags: adsense-api

I'm working on an application to connect to the Google Adsense API. As I'm based in the UK, my reports on the Google Adsense web login are all set to UK local time. However, the API data all seems to be solely in Pacific Time, AKA Google Standard Time :-)

This isn't necessarily a huge issue, as it doesn't affect actual earnings. But it does make it harder to track things like CPC and CTR on a daily basis. It would be easier if I could drill down into the data to hourly level, as then I could easily reallocate out-of-zone hours to the adjacent day. But that doesn't seem to be an option either, unless I'm missing something.

I've searched the documentation, but can't seem to find any means of controlling the timezone of API data. Is there any way to get the APi to deliver the data in a local timezone, or do I just have to put up with getting my reports in Pacific time?

Comment: It's just a thought, but I think that the data is tracked by where the activity occured.

Comment: The data is always saved in Pacific Time Zone and in a local time zone if configured by the AdSense user.

Answer (score 1):

As a developer you can't define a time zone to use, but as a publisher you can change your local time zone in the AdSense web interface. After that, you can use useTimezoneReporting when requesting a report.

Read the full explanation and "Things to watch out for" in:

https://developers.google.com/adsense/management/timezone

Answer (score 0):

Situated in the UK, I request a saved report from AdSense API and with "yesterdays" data.

When triggered after midnight our time it pulls data from the day before yesterday...

I didn't know the API was functioning on PST time and just believed it would follow the local timezone set on our account.

Even though the documentation in the comment above mentions reports will be done in "local time" when set in your account, the API will still operate calls based on its own timezone (PST). +8 hours GMT.

So if you need to get "yesterdays" report, be sure to set the date on your call or adjust your schedule to match the PST time zone.